# CSS Transitions re-playing on browser tab switch. How can I get around this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need some help with my code. I have a smooth transition that changes the colour of a password fields border when it is focussed. However, when I switch to and from a different tab after the colour change, it replays the transition even if the field is still focussed.

What I want is for the transition to play once and stay the different border colour until clicked off. I put some of my code here for easy viewing: https://jsfiddle.net/b38z4ma2/. Here you can replicate my issue.

1. focus(click) on the input field
2. see the transition
3. switch browser tab and back again
4. the transition will re play. <- I do not want this part!

Also here is the plain code

```
:root {
    --darkdark-gray: #222428;
    --dark-gray: #2F3136;
    --mid-gray: #36393F;
    --light-gray: #888C91;
    --blurple: #7289DA;
    --blurple-shade: #677BC4;
    --whiteish: #DCDDDE;
    --white: #FFFFFF;

    --shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

body {
    background-color: var(--dark-gray);
}

#container {
    background-color: var(--mid-gray);
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    box-shadow: var(--shadow);
}

input {
    width: 750px;
    height: 50px;
    transform: translate(50px, 50px);
    background-color: var(--dark-gray);
    border: 2px solid var(--darkdark-gray);
    border-radius: 6px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: var(--whiteish);
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-family: Whitney, sans-serif;
}

input:focus {
    border-color: var(--blurple);
    transition: border 2s;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="password-container">
            <label>
                <input type="password">
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Perhaps there is a javascript solution? Please no jQuery! Thanks to anyone that can help, this may seem a small issue but it is really bugging me.